# Instafeed changing tagged value by input

Tags: javascript, instafeedjs

I trying to change my tagged name by input, once enter key pressed it will re-run by `feed.run();`

```
var num = 60;
var inputTextValue;




window.onkeyup = keyup;
    function keyup(e) {
      inputTextValue = e.target.value;
      $('#searchValue').text(inputTextValue);

      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          inputTextValue = e.target.value;
          feed.run();

      }
    }

    var feed = new Instafeed({
   get: 'tagged',
   tagName: inputTextValue,
    userId: 3614616,
    accessToken: '3614616.467ede5.abc0b5a861d34365a5c8dd8db0163c4b',
    limit:"100",
    resolution : "low_resolution",
    after: function () {
    var images = $("#instafeed").find('a');
    $.each(images, function(index, image) {
      var delay = (index * 75) + 'ms';
      $(image).css('-webkit-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-moz-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-ms-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-o-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).addClass('animated flipInX');
    });
  },
  template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /><div class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div></a>'
});
```

and with this I will get a error

```
No tag name specified. Use the 'tagName' option.
```

Any idea can get update the tagged name value?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the issue you are running into deals with how variables are passed to functions in JavaScript.

Strings are "passed by value", which in your case means that `inputTextValue`'s value is getting **copied** to Instafeed.js at the time you create your instance by doing `new Instafeed({ .. });`.

This also means that when you change `inputTextValue`'s value later on, it **will not** update the Instafeed.js settings (because it was *copied* when you set up Instafeed.js).

In order to work around this, you'll want to directly update the Instafeed.js settings by changing a property on your `feed` variable. Here's a slightly modified version of your original script:

```
var num = 60;
var inputTextValue;
var feed = new Instafeed({
  get: 'tagged',
  tagName: 'placeholder',
  userId: 3614616,
  accessToken: '3614616.467ede5.abc0b5a861d34365a5c8dd8db0163c4b',
  limit:"100",
  resolution : "low_resolution",
  after: function () {
    var images = $("#instafeed").find('a');
    $.each(images, function(index, image) {
      var delay = (index * 75) + 'ms';
      $(image).css('-webkit-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-moz-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-ms-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-o-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).addClass('animated flipInX');
    });
  },
  template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /><div class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div></a>'
});

window.onkeyup = keyup;

function keyup(e) {
  inputTextValue = e.target.value;
  $('#searchValue').text(inputTextValue);

  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    inputTextValue = e.target.value;
    feed.options.tagName = inputTextValue; // forceably update instafeed.js settings.
    feed.run();
  }
}
```